# How to save from javascript/jquery dropdown value using php to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently making a form that contains two dropdown list on the 1st dropdown named 'module' Once the user select an option the 2nd dropdown named 'items' will be updated depending on the selected option from the 1st dropdown. I used a simple html select on the 1st dropdown on the 2nd I used javacript/jquery in order to have it auto update. Now the problem is upon saving the 1st dropdown is saving in mysql via php, the 2nd dropdown is not saving , I'm not really familiar with javascript/jquery so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Hoping someone can enlighten me on this problem thanks in advance!

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#module").change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      $("select[name = items]").html(options1[val]);
    });



    var options1 = [
      "<option value=''>----</option>",

      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='1'>Hotel Info & General Notes</option><option value='Contact details'>Contact details</option><option value='Market Policy (TA Location/Residency/Nationality)'>Market Policy (TA Location/Residency/Nationality)</option><option value='Payment method'>Payment method</option><option value='Profile not updated'>Profile not updated</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Closeout travel period'>Closeout travel period</option><option value='Closeout not created/removed'>Closeout not created/removed</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Created/Extended checklist'>Created/Extended checklist</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Room name'>Room name</option><option value='Max occupancy'>Max occupancy</option><option value='Child age'>Child age</option><option value='Extra bed'>Extra bed</option><option value='Room type not created/removed'>Room type not created/removed</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Rate Type (Flexible/NRF/APR)'>Rate Type (Flexible/NRF/APR)</option><option value='Rate Plan Code/Rate Code/Promo Code'>Rate Plan Code/Rate Code/Promo Code</option><option value='Rate Currency'>Rate Currency</option><option value='Board Basis/Meal Type'>Board Basis/Meal Type</option><option value='Applicable Markets'>Applicable Markets</option><option value='Travel Period'>Travel Period</option><option value='Booking Period'>Booking Period</option><option value='Adult Rate'>Adult Rate</option><option value='Child Age'>Child Age</option><option value='Child Rate'>Child Rate</option><option value='Child Availability'>Child Availability</option><option value='Extra Bed Rate'>Extra Bed Rate</option><option value='Extra Bed Availability'>Extra Bed Availability</option><option value='Cancellation Policy'>Cancellation Policy</option><option value='No Show Policy'>No Show Policy</option><option value='Availability - Type (Alloc./FS/FFS)'>Availability - Type (Alloc./FS/FFS)</option><option value='Availability - Incorrect no. of rooms'>Availability - Incorrect no. of rooms</option><option value='Availability - Not pooled across rates'>Availability - Not pooled across rates</option><option value='Availability - Alloc/FS/FFS not loaded'>Availability - Alloc/FS/FFS not loaded</option><option value='Release Period - Day'>Release Period - Day</option><option value='Release Period - Time'>Release Period - Time</option><option value='Min. Length of Stay'>Min. Length of Stay</option><option value='Max. Length of Stay'>Max. Length of Stay</option><option value='Min./Max Length of Stay Applicable if'>Min./Max Length of Stay Applicable if</option><option value='Check-in Restriction'>Check-in Restriction</option><option value='Check-out Restriction'>Check-out Restriction</option><option value='Rate Closeout'>Rate Closeout</option><option value='Rate Notes'>Rate Notes</option><option value='New rate not loaded'>New rate not loaded</option><option value='Promo combinations incorrectly/not applied'>Promo combinations incorrectly/not applied</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Tax Name'>Tax Name</option><option value='Tax Travel Period'>Tax Travel Period</option><option value='Tax Type (Percentage/Fixed Amount)'>Tax Type (Percentage/Fixed Amount)</option><option value='Tax Amount'>Tax Amount</option><option value='Tax Category'>Tax Category</option><option value='Tax not loaded/extended'>Tax not loaded/extended</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Supp. Name'>Supp. Name</option><option value='Supp. Travel Period'>Supp. Travel Period</option><option value='Supp. applied per room/per person'>Supp. applied per room/per person</option><option value='Supp. Currency'>Supp. Currency</option><option value='Supp. Rate'>Supp. Rate</option><option value='Supp. Rate include Tax'>Supp. Rate include Tax</option><option value='Supp. not loaded'>Supp. not loaded</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Mand. Serv. Name'>Mand. Serv. Name</option><option value='Mand. Serv. Travel Period'>Mand. Serv. Travel Period</option><option value='Mand. Serv. applied per room/per person'>Mand. Serv. applied per room/per person</option><option value='Mand. Serv. applied upon check-in/check-out'>Mand. Serv. applied upon check-in/check-out</option><option value='Mand. Serv. Rate'>Mand. Serv. Rate</option><option value='Mand. Serv. Apply to Selected Markets'>Mand. Serv. Apply to Selected Markets</option><option value='Mand. Serv. Apply to Selected Rate Codes'>Mand. Serv. Apply to Selected Rate Codes</option><option value='Mand. Serv. not loaded'>Mand. Serv. not loaded</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Extra Meal Travel Period'>Extra Meal Travel Period</option><option value='Extra Meal Type'>Extra Meal Type</option><option value='Extra Meal Name'>Extra Meal Name</option><option value='Extra Meal Adult Rate'>Extra Meal Adult Rate</option><option value='Extra Meal Child Age'>Extra Meal Child Age</option><option value='Extra Meal Child Rate'>Extra Meal Child Rate</option><option value='Extra Meal Tax'>Extra Meal Tax</option><option value='Extra Meal Discount'>Extra Meal Discount</option><option value='Extra Meal not loaded'>Extra Meal not loaded</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Availability pooled across contract checklists'>Availability pooled across contract checklists</option><option value='Availability pooled across rooms'>Availability pooled across rooms</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Allocation closed/opened'>Allocation closed/opened</option><option value='Freesale closed/opened'>Freesale closed/opened</option><option value='Framed Freesale closed/opened'>Framed Freesale closed/opened</option><option value='Top Up Allocation closed/opened'>Top Up Allocation closed/opened</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Promo Travel Period'>Promo Travel Period</option><option value='Promo Booking Period'>Promo Booking Period</option><option value='Promo Closeouts'>Promo Closeouts</option><option value='Promo Lead Time'>Promo Lead Time</option><option value='Promo Check-in Day of Week'>Promo Check-in Day of Week</option><option value='Promo Code'>Promo Code</option><option value='Promo Name'>Promo Name</option><option value='Promo Applicable Markets'>Promo Applicable Markets</option><option value='Promo Type'>Promo Type</option><option value='Promo Min. Length of Stay'>Promo Min. Length of Stay</option><option value='Promo Max. Length of Stay'>Promo Max. Length of Stay</option><option value='Promo Stay Nights'>Promo Stay Nights</option><option value='Promo Pay Nights (Stay X Pay Y)'>Promo Pay Nights (Stay X Pay Y)</option><option value='Promo Free night(s) applied on (Stay X Pay Y)'>Promo Free night(s) applied on (Stay X Pay Y)</option><option value='Promo Free night(s) Board Basis (Stay X Pay Y)'>Promo Free night(s) Board Basis (Stay X Pay Y)</option><option value='Promo Stay Nights+ (Stay X Get %)'>Promo Stay Nights+ (Stay X Get %)</option><option value='Promo Discount (Stay X Get %)'>Promo Discount (Stay X Get %)</option><option value='Promo Hide promotion percent (Stay X Get %)'>Promo Hide promotion percent (Stay X Get %)</option><option value='Promo Discount on Board Basis (Stay X Get %)'>Promo Discount on Board Basis (Stay X Get %)</option><option value='Promo Apply to Extra Bed (Stay X Get %)'>Promo Apply to Extra Bed (Stay X Get %)</option><option value='Promo Apply to Child Policy (Stay X Get %)'>Promo Apply to Child Policy (Stay X Get %)</option><option value='Promo Upgrade To (Free Room/Meal Upgrade)'>Promo Upgrade To (Free Room/Meal Upgrade)</option><option value='Promo Package Description (VAS)'>Promo Package Description (VAS)</option><option value='Promo Applicable if'>Promo Applicable if</option><option value='Promo Applicable to taxes'>Promo Applicable to taxes</option><option value='Promo can be applied multiple times'>Promo can be applied multiple times</option><option value='Promo Day of Week'>Promo Day of Week</option><option value='Promo applied to correct room type/rate'>Promo applied to correct room type/rate</option><option value='Promo Temp not loaded (incl. for other meal types)'>Promo Temp not loaded (incl. for other meal types)</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Transfers'>Transfers</option>",
      "<option value=''>----</option><option value='Tours'>Tours</option>"
    ];



  });


 </script>
```

```html
<?php
 if(empty($exist1)){
                      $query80="insert into markdown(module,item,ticket_id,date_received,qa) VALUES('".$mo."','".$item."','".$ticket1."','".$date_received."','".$user."')";
                      $result80=mysqli_query($datalog,$query80);
                     
                     }
                     elseif(!empty($exist1)){
                       $query55="UPDATE markdown SET module='".$mo."',item='".$item."',date_received='".$date_received."',qa='".$user."' WHERE ticket_id='$ticket1'";
                      $result55=mysqli_query($datalog,$query55);
                      echo '1',$module,$item;
                     }
                     
                     
                     ?>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:200px;height:25px;" id="module" name="module">
 <option value="0">---- </option>
    <option value="1">Profile</option>
 <option value="2">Closeouts</option>
    <option value="3">Contract Checklist</option>
 <option value="4">Room Types</option>
 <option value="5">Rates and Inventory</option>
 <option value="6">Taxes</option>
 <option value="7">Supplements</option>
    <option value="8">Mandatory Services</option>
 <option value="9">Extra Meals</option>
 <option value="10">Allotment Pools</option>
 <option value="11">Room Type Fast Stop Sell</option>
 <option value="12">Promotion Template</option>
 <option value="13">Transfers</option>
 <option value="14">Tours</option>
</select>

<select name="items" style="width:200px; height:25px;">
</select>
```

Comment: I suppose it should be `$("select[name=items]")`

Comment: What triggers the saving of items?

Comment: @TanDuong tried changing it still not saving, I'm thinking there might be a problem with the transfer of value from javascript to php

Comment: @SachiTekina there's another select box that when values are set the php code above will get the values from both the dropdown boxes and save it to the database , The 1st dropdownbox "module" is saving the 2nd dropdownbox "items" is not saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the thing is that when the page load, it loads with event attach on the element so we can use them easily via jQuery or javascript with suppose:

```
$('#element').on('click',function(){
})
```

But your second select drop-down has is options coming from php on event of select 1 after page has loaded so there are no event attached to them.

But fortunately we can reference them by parent :

```
    $('PresentParentSincePageLoad').on('click', 'elementYouJustLoaded', 
           function(e){
var element = $(this);
    })
```

I hope to have helped

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the error as the name of the 2nd dropdown box did not match the name of the indicated on the php code